# sql date for year start

Tags: sql, date

I require a piece of sql code which shows me the year part of a specific date, however the new year should start on november 1st.

for example the below two will bring me 2014 :

```
select DATEPART(year, '2014-10-01')
select DATEPART(year, '2014-11-01')
```

How I need the second one to return 2015 as the new year for the company starts in november.

I also need this to not only work for the 2 specified years but for any date. someone told me it was as easy as minus-ing 2 months etc Thank you

Comment: Use dateadd to add two months to the date, then use datepart to get the year. You can easily do that in one statement.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `datepart()` is a non-standard function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two months and get the year part of it.

```
 select datepart(year, dateadd(MONTH,2,'2014-10-01')), -- 2014
 datepart(year, dateadd(MONTH,2,'2014-11-01')) -- 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MS SQL Server...

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH,2,'2014-11-01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PostgreSQL

```
SELECT
date_part('year', ('2014-10-01') :: DATE + INTERVAL '2 months'), -- 2014
date_part('year', ('2014-11-01') :: DATE + INTERVAL '2 months'); -- 2015;
```